# using python pandas to filter row value that within that dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, decimal, transformation

i'm very new to python transformation world using pandas! I'm here to asking some code problem stuck by myself.
For my case, i'm using python pandas to **filter row value without eliminate them - as just select them out without delete them from the dataframe column** within that dataframe column. However, within that dataframe column consist of **mixed of float**(value more than 2 decimal places) **and integer** (consist only one decimal place which the output as `x.0`)
for this dataframe column, in python pandas dataframe, it does default assume that column's datatype to `float64`, so it's hard for me to determine/filter using `isinstance()` and alternative function/ way to deal with this type mixed data type column without eliminate the unwanted value

Below is a mock of my dataset which structure from a dataframe:

```
data = {
'time': [00.00.01,00.00.02,00.00.03,00.00.04,00.00.05,00.00.06,00.00.07,00.00.08,00.00.09,00.00.10,00.00.11,00.00.12,
00.00.13,00.00.14,00.00.15,00.00.16,00.00.17,00.00.18,00.00.19,00.00.20,00.00.21,00.00.22,00.00.23,00.00.24],
'value': [1.234, 2.345, 3.456, 4.567, 5.678, 6.789, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1.234, 2.345, 3.456, 4.567, 5.678, 6.789, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

while print out as a dataframe, the data looks like:

```
> time value
1 00.00.1 1.234
2 00.00.2 2.345
3 00.00.3 3.456
4 00.00.4 4.567
5 00.00.5 5.678
6 00.00.6 6.789
7 00.00.7 1.0
8 00.00.8 2.0
9 00.00.9 3.0
10 00.00.10 4.0
11 00.00.11 5.0
12 00.00.12 6.0
13 00.00.13 1.234
14 00.00.14 2.345
15 00.00.15 3.456
16 00.00.16 4.567
17 00.00.17 5.678
18 00.00.18 6.789
19 00.00.19 1.0
20 00.00.10 2.0
21 00.00.21 3.0
22 00.00.22 4.0
23 00.00.23 5.0
24 00.00.24 6.0
```

I've tried for the below solution to fix this problem with.
**-My solution-**
this will remove the values that with only one decimal place while keep the value more than one decimal places.

```
value = data[(data['value'].astype(str).str.split('.').str[1].str.len()>1)]
```

and the printed output might be like:

```
> time value
0 00.00.1 1.234
1 00.00.2 2.345
2 00.00.3 3.456
3 00.00.4 4.567
4 00.00.5 5.678
5 00.00.6 6.789
13 00.00.13 1.234
14 00.00.14 2.345
15 00.00.15 3.456
16 00.00.16 4.567
17 00.00.17 5.678
18 00.00.18 6.789
```

I'm expecting a dataframe could get a result like this without eliminate any unwanted row values even though there is undergoing a filter to select only the value with only one decimal place:

```
> time value
1 00.00.1 1.234
2 00.00.2 2.345
3 00.00.3 3.456
4 00.00.4 4.567
5 00.00.5 5.678
6 00.00.6 6.789
7 00.00.7 1.0
8 00.00.8 2.0
9 00.00.9 3.0
10 00.00.10 4.0
11 00.00.11 5.0
12 00.00.12 6.0
13 00.00.13 1.234
14 00.00.14 2.345
15 00.00.15 3.456
16 00.00.16 4.567
17 00.00.17 5.678
18 00.00.18 6.789
19 00.00.19 1.0
20 00.00.10 2.0
21 00.00.21 3.0
22 00.00.22 4.0
23 00.00.23 5.0
24 00.00.24 6.0
```

I really do need your help to fix this problem, thanks in advance!

Comment: In short, do you need to select a subset from dataframe where the ```value``` column has some decimal value which is not zero?

Comment: What's wrong with your code???

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. For this case, do not need to perform subset as actually for my real dataset, consists of multiple columns like `value` , so i did subset before dip into this part of problem. For this column, no any not zero or negative values for the values in the columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*What you want is really unclear*:

> filter row value without eliminate them - as just select them out without delete them from the dataframe column.

In this case, just use a boolean mask without selecting data from your dataframe:

```
m = data['value'].ne(data['value'].round())
```

Output:

```
# boolean mask
>>> m
1      True
2      True
3      True
4      True
5      True
6      True
7     False
8     False
9     False
10    False
11    False
12    False
13     True
14     True
15     True
16     True
17     True
18     True
19    False
20    False
21    False
22    False
23    False
24    False
Name: value, dtype: bool

# selection
>>> data[m]
        time  value
1    00.00.1  1.234
2    00.00.2  2.345
3    00.00.3  3.456
4    00.00.4  4.567
5    00.00.5  5.678
6    00.00.6  6.789
13  00.00.13  1.234
14  00.00.14  2.345
15  00.00.15  3.456
16  00.00.16  4.567
17  00.00.17  5.678
18  00.00.18  6.789
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution and explanation to the term- boolean mask. I'm apologize to my poor explanation on this problem, and will try to improve it! And I'd tried your solution, which it halfway works but the final output still remain the same.

Comment: I don't understand what you expect. Can you provide a different example with more real data as input and the expected result, please?